# What should I do if I see the case when someone is answering his/her own question just to gain reputation points

Tags: discussion

I observed a user on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ who was several time asking questions and then accepting its own answer. A couple of the questions are asked and answers accepted exactly at the same time. One of the questions was asked and answered on 'Mar 17 at 8:39' , the second question is asked and answered on 'Mar 21 at 16:07'. My assumption is that person was just gaining points of reputation. What is the best action to take now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question. I'm glad you asked. It smells like something that's bad. But what should we do?

### Nothing. The system is working as intended.

Asking a question and posting an immediate answer is one of the intended features of Stack Exchange. Basically, the original visions of Stack Overflow (which evolved into Stack Exchange) is a special Venn Diagram of existing services. In this case, it seems like this user is leveraging the Blog corner of the diagram.

If the question is good (forget the self-answer, focus on the question) then the question deserves an up-vote. If it doesn't, it deserves a down-vote, an edit, or a flag.

If the answer is good (forget that it's also asked by the guy) it deserves an upvote. If it doesn't, it deserves a down-vote, an edit, or a flag.

If the user has posted junk questions or answers, they should get handled separately.

If the user has posted valuable information that will be useful to future visitors... where's the problem? :-)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I wouldn't really bring this discussion up but one of the questions was just a replication from help file. So, it gives very little value. But okay, now I see that questions like that deserves downvote. Plese correct me if I'm wrong but shouldn't it be allowed to accept own questions in 48 hours after it's been asked?

Comment: You can accept your own answer after some amount of time (I forget the specifics) but you do not gain the +15 reputation for doing so. You only get that for answering someone else's question.